# Drag an image without losing original in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, touch, avaudioplayer

Can we drag an image from one place to another without losing the original.

eg: i have images in uiscrollview , Now i want to drag an image from uiscrollview to another uiimageview which is out of uiscrollview.

But i want to show the image in both places.

Because , i want to add an image to Audio song by dragging from the UiScrollView.

Is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible why don't you just copy the image and put the copy on the UIImageView?

Comment: i want to display dragging an image

Comment: You mean animating the dragging action`?

Comment: yes , when i am dragging image, it will show like dragging an image from our desktop.

Comment: Well the answer is yes it is possible. What is the specific problem you have doing this?

Comment: What do you mean with won't be dragged completely? Where does it stop? So you do manage to drag it in a segment?